# disable enter key until user inputs a character?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

how would you disable the usage of the enter key on a text area until a character is entered?

this is for a form i'm building - purely for aesthetic reasons :-)

a bit like the facebook news feed page where you can't press enter until entering a single character?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could have mentioned you using jQuery. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$("textarea").live("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.which === 13 && $(this).val() === "")
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that if your goal is to avoid any new line characters at the top of a textarea, this won't prevent someone from pasting in new lines.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add an event handler to listen and trap the return key conditionally. This should point you in the right direction

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php